Having issue connecting to Milvus running inside Docker
I start Milvus using docker-compose and this file. All three of the components (minio, etcd, and milvus standalone) start just fine and are running.
I am also able to connect to the Milvus container from my desktop using "localhost" and the Milvus CLI tool for Mac.  However, when I try to connect to the Milvus container from another container inside docker (using the same docker network), I get the following error.
FWIW, I can ping the Milvus container from the other container, and nslookup milvus-standalone  returns the correct IP address in the docker network
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize connection. Error: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: deadline exceeded after 9.845632375s. [closed=[], open=[[wait_for_ready, buffered_nanos=9847330880, waiting_for_connection]]]
        at io.milvus.client.MilvusServiceClient.<init>(MilvusServiceClient.java:154) ~[?:?]
        at dev.langchain4j.store.embedding.milvus.MilvusEmbeddingStore.<init>(MilvusEmbeddingStore.java:102) ~[?:?]

services:
  etcd:
    container_name: milvus-etcd
    image: quay.io/coreos/etcd:v3.5.0
    platform: linux/amd64
    environment:
      - ETCD_AUTO_COMPACTION_MODE=revision
      - ETCD_AUTO_COMPACTION_RETENTION=1000
      - ETCD_QUOTA_BACKEND_BYTES=4294967296
    volumes:
      - ${DOCKER_VOLUME_DIRECTORY:-.}/volumes/etcd:/etcd
    command: etcd -advertise-client-urls=http://127.0.0.1:2379 -listen-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:2379 --data-dir /etcd

  minio:
    container_name: milvus-minio
    image: minio/minio:RELEASE.2020-12-03T00-03-10Z
    platform: linux/amd64
    environment:
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: minioadmin
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: minioadmin
    volumes:
      - ${DOCKER_VOLUME_DIRECTORY:-.}/volumes/minio:/minio_data
    command: minio server /minio_data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:9000/minio/health/live"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 3

  standalone:
    container_name: milvus-standalone
    image: milvusdb/milvus:v2.4.1
    platform: linux/amd64
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '4'
          memory: 8G
        reservations:
          cpus: '2'
          memory: 4G
    command: ["milvus", "run", "standalone"]
    environment:
      ETCD_ENDPOINTS: etcd:2379
      MINIO_ADDRESS: minio:9000
    volumes:
      - ${DOCKER_VOLUME_DIRECTORY:-.}/volumes/milvus:/var/lib/milvus
    ports:
      - "19530:19530"
      - "9091:9091"
    depends_on:
      - "etcd"
      - "minio"

networks:
  default:
    name: gen-ai-demo

Any suggestions on solving this? Thank you for any help in advance.

Can we get helm chart for the above to create and run the above setup. What we are looking is a way to deploy these components in AKS cluster

Assuming the "other" container is started in the same docker instance as the app you're trying to connect to, you should use the container name given in the docker-compose file, not localhost, when connecting.  Make sure the "other" container is running on the same named docker network as the app you're trying to connect to.
As described in the following link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-communicate-between-docker-containers-via-hostname/
Docker will assign an arbitrary IP address to each container, and internal dns will assign that name you provide in the docker-compose file.

Can we get helm chart for the above to create and run the above setup. What we are looking is a way to deploy these components in AKS cluster
